# Create chart in excel that will compare different sessions on the same timeline

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, google-spreadsheets

I have three devices that report battery percentage to my server every 15 minutes. The exact time that the devices report can vary. I took a sample of the three devices over a period of about 30 hours and collected the data in an excel sheet:

[image: Example - 1]

I also tried to represent it in a different way as follows:

[image: Example - 2]

I am trying to make a line chart that displays the three devices on a common timeline according to the timestamps associated with each event. But for some reason the first device I add is showing correctly according to its time stamps and when I am trying to add the rest they show at the wrong hours on the chart:

Example:

[image: See that the 17 value on the chart is showing at a different hour than in the spreadsheet]

I am not so used to work with excel and google sheets in this manner and I just don't understand what I am doing wrong. I can create three different graphs and it works well.

BTW these examples are from google sheets but I tried in excel and got similar results. I just hate that you need to format everything in excel its weird.

Comment: How about using a single column for time and a column for each device. All rows do not need to be filled for all devices, just make sure you use the "Connect data points with line" option (Select Data -> Hidden and Empty Cells)

Comment: You can copy 3 columns of dates into one column and use the Data > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates feature to remove duplicate datetimes. Then use Vlookup function to search the battery value for eache device. The "#N/A" can be set "Show #N/A as an empty cell" in chart after following cybernetic.nomad suggestions.